# Making all lines one space inside than the rest in c

Tags: c

I have this code which prints a simple square

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, b;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b <= n + 1; b++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to make it do is to print every line one space more inside than the first and last, like this:

For n = 3

```
 ****
****
 ****
```

For n = 7

```
   ********
  ********
 *********
**********
 *********
  ********
   ********
```

The first and last lines are fixed but they are being increased as n is getting increased, and every other line is one space more inside but its being increased by one star from the previous line

Comment: For C, `for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)` is an *anti-pattern* and best un-learned as fast as possible. Otherwise, you *will* run into problems with this when your next lesson introduces you to arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code outputs exactly the rules implied by you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, b;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // First part until half of N (1 --> N/2)
    for(i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        for (b = i; b <= n / 2; b++)
            printf(" ");
        if(i == 1)
            for (b = 1; b <= n + i; b++)
                printf("*");
        else 
            for (b = 1; b <= n + i - 1; b++)
                printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }

    // The line at half of N
    for(i = 1; i <= n + (n / 2); i++)
        printf("*");
    printf("\n");

    // Last part until N is reached (N/2 --> N)
    for(i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        for (b = 1; b <= i; b++)
            printf(" ");
        if(i == n/2)
            for (b = 1; b <= n + 1; b++)
                printf("*");
        else
            for (b = 1; b <= n + (n / 2) - i; b++)
                printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result is the following:

For N = 3

```
 ****
****
 ****
```

For N = 7

```
   ********                                                                                                             
  ********                                                                                                              
 *********                                                                                                              
**********                                                                                                              
 *********                                                                                                              
  ********                                                                                                              
   ********
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the following output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, b;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int offset = (n / 2) - (i - 1);
        if(offset < 0)
            offset = -offset;
        for(b = 1; b <= offset; b++)
            printf(" ");

        for (b = 1; b <= n + 1; b++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter number of rows: 3
 ****
****
 ****

Enter number of rows: 7
   ********
  ********
 ********
********
 ********
  ********
   ********
```

Answer (score 1):

And this version also works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, b;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {

    if (i<(n/2) +1){
        for (b = i; b < n/2 + 1; b++){
            printf(" ");
        }
    }else{
        for (b = i ; b != (n/2) +1; b--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }

        for (b = 1; b <= n + 1; b++){
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```